# What is DHCP Name Server?

Tags: networking, dhcp

It is definitely not DNS right? I am looking at a tutorial for configuring router and he put DHCP Name Server as 192.168.99.100 and secondary DHCP Name Server as 8.8.8.8. I understand DHCP Server as a server that provide dynamic IPs to client. However, in that case then why can 8.8.8.8 be used to provide dynamic IP to my local devices?

Reference link https://youtu.be/HcfIpTso_Ys?t=747

Comment: Those are the DNS settings that are being distributed to the DHCP clients, so in this example the clients will use 192.168.99.100 as their primary DNS server, and 8.8.8.8 as their secondary.

Comment: I see thank you! Somehow the term DHCP Name Server is not easily found on internet

Comment: See this...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

Comment: There is a reason : There is no such think as a DHCP Name Server, only of DHCP Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the DNS settings that are being distributed to the DHCP clients, so in this example the clients will use 192.168.99.1 as their primary DNS server, and 8.8.8.8 as their secondary.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that’s a slip up on Ubiquiti’s end. It drives me crazy.